# Header name duplications

Tags: paw-app

Is this normal behavior, that Header name duplicates the same amount of times as it used in other requests? 
[image: Header name duplications]

**Update:**
Paw version 2.2.3

Maybe there is some sort of cache? Because I see duplication even in new document.

**Update:**
Paw version: 2.2.4

It looks better now, but still one duplication exists

[image]

Comment: Are you running Paw 2.2.3? I think we fixed this issue in the latest version, which is released on our website, but sill pending validation for the Mac App Store.

Comment: Yep, version is 2.2.3 and problem is still presented

Comment: Ok! Will have a look and a fix asap, thanks for reporting